# Request headers set on a webview not being passed through

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have implemented a custom web view renderer, with a custom WebViewClient as below.  However, the new headers aren't making it as far as the page. What have I missed?

"otherheader" makes it through (but only on the first request), but "mysource" does not.

WebViewClient

```
public class MyWebViewClient : WebViewClient
{
    public override WebResourceResponse ShouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, IWebResourceRequest urlResource)
    {
        if (!urlResource.RequestHeaders.ContainsKey("mysource"))
        {
            urlResource.RequestHeaders.Add("mysource", "app");
        }

        return base.ShouldInterceptRequest(view, urlResource);
    }
}
```

CustomRenderer

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(HybridWebView), typeof(HybridWebViewRenderer))]
namespace CustomRenderer.Droid
{
    public class HybridWebViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<HybridWebView, Android.Webkit.WebView>
    {
        Context _context;

        public HybridWebViewRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<HybridWebView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control == null)
            {
                var webView = new Android.Webkit.WebView(_context);
                webView.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
                webView.SetWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
                SetNativeControl(webView);
            }
            if (e.OldElement != null)
            {
                var hybridWebView = e.OldElement as HybridWebView;
                hybridWebView.Cleanup();
            }
            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                IDictionary<string, string> headers = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                headers.Add("otherheader", "yes");
                Control.LoadUrl(e.NewElement.Uri, headers);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should return a new `WebResourceResponse` instead of `return base.ShouldInterceptRequest(view, urlResource);`.

For example:

```
public override WebResourceResponse ShouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, IWebResourceRequest urlResource)
{
    if (!urlResource.RequestHeaders.ContainsKey("mysource"))
    {
        urlResource.RequestHeaders.Add("mysource", "app");
    }
    var client = new HttpClient();

    var result = client.GetAsync(urlResource.Url,ToString()).Result;
    string contentType = result.Content.Headers.ContentType.ToString();
    var stream = result.Content.ReadStreamAsync().Result;

    return new WebResourceResponse("text/html", "charset=utf-8", (int)result.StatusCode, result.ReasonPhrase, urlResource.RequestHeaders, stream);
}
```

Comment: Why are you setting the response headers to the request headers in the response? Shouldn't these be sent to the the server by the client?